# Avalanche runout analysis within the latest TauDEM-package does not work (Error 000732: Parameters are not vaild)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, arcgis-10.4, error-000732, taudem

I am trying to calculate the runout of avalanches with the TauDEM-toolbox (Version 5.3.7). I am running ArcGIS 10.4 and Windows 10.
I have tried using the sample data provided, following their tutorial and and it worked. When I am using my data (which I converted from .asc into .tif format with QGIS beforehand) I get the following message: ExecuteError: Failed to execute: Parameters are not valid.

[image: tauDEM message]

All data have the same coordinate system as well as the same projection.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour.  Please place error messages inside the question  as text, which will both make the message legible on all devices and allow others to locate your question with a free text search. You should also provide more details on the parameters provided to the utility, and the coordinate references involved (in both the working and non-working datasets. Please **edit** the question.

Answer (score 1):

After each TauDEM function is run, the Python script that wraps this calculates uses an arcpy.calculateStatistics_management function on the results so that when they are added to ArcGIS they display nicely.  In this case this function is indicating that the file it needs was not found, which means it was not written by the TauDEM function.  Text in the tool output window above the text shown in the screen shot may indicate the problem.

A common problem with setting up inputs for a tool like this for TauDEM is that the dimensions (rows, columns, cell size) of the input grids have to match exactly (TauDEM does not do interpolations when doing cell by cell calculations).  It is likely that your avalanche source site "Ass" grid (because you have to provide this independently of any other TauDEM results) has different dimensions.  Try use the Environment Setting -> Processing Extent option to set the Extent and Snap Raster the same as one of the TauDEM rasters. A Raster Calculator Map Algebra expression that just evaluates your current input with TauDEM raster used in the Environment Settings could achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

David Tarboton provided me the following answer: Rows and columns have to match exactly in both data sets. Normally there is an error message if these parameters don´t match but in my case the program was aborting before printing this message.

Answer (score 0):

A little follow up in case anyone else runs across this problem:

All three inputs - the *Pit Filled Elevation Grid*,  the *Flow Direction Grid* and the Avalanche Source Site Grid - have to have the same exact size. This means that the number of columns and rows have to be identical **PLUS** the extent has to start on the same pixel (origin).

If the extent is off, even by a fraction of a meter (e.g. 100000 v. 100000.00001 for UTM) then the process will return ERROR 000732 and fail.